# Using index on parent enumeration

Tags: enumerate

I want to use index of parent enumeration in child enumeration.
For example,

```
\begin{enumerate}
\item the 
\item quick 
\begin {enumerate}
\item brown
\item fox 
\end {enumerate}
\item jumps 
\begin {enumerate}
\item over
\item the
\begin {enumerate}
\item lazy
\end {enumerate}
\end {enumerate}
\item dog
\end{enumerate}
```

will print:

(1) the

(2) quick

(2.1) brown

(2.2) fox

(3) jumps

(3.1) over

(3.2) the

(3.2.1) lazy

(4) dog

Actually I found a formatting to use (num) stuff:

```
[label=(\arabic*)]
```

However, I have no idea to use parent's index.

Comment: Do you want the labels to be flush with the left margin, or should inner lists be indented with respect to the outer one?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With `enumitem`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[label=(\arabic*)]
\item the
\item quick
\begin {enumerate}[label=(\arabic{enumi}.\arabic*)]
\item brown
\item fox
\end {enumerate}
\item jumps
\begin {enumerate}[label=(\arabic{enumi}.\arabic*)]
\item over
\item the
\begin {enumerate}[label=(\arabic{enumi}.\arabic{enumii}.\arabic*)]
\item lazy
\end {enumerate}
\end {enumerate}
\item dog
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

There is also `label*` which will append the parent's label, but as you want parenthesis here, it may not be suitable.

If you want labels to be flush to the left margin, add this in the preamble:

```
\setlist[enumerate,1,2,3]{wide}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

The environment is `enumerate` not `enumeration`
[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\renewcommand\theenumii{\theenumi.\arabic{enumii}}
\renewcommand\theenumiii{\theenumii.\arabic{enumiii}}
\renewcommand\labelenumi{(\theenumi)}
\renewcommand\labelenumii{(\theenumii)}
\renewcommand\labelenumiii{(\theenumiii)}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item the 
\item quick 
\begin {enumerate}
\item brown
\item fox 
\end {enumerate}
\item jumps 
\begin {enumerate}
\item over
\item the
\begin {enumerate}
\item lazy
\end {enumerate}
\end {enumerate}
\item dog
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I got that far, but got stuck on left-aligning all the labels...

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes I assumed the left alignment in the question was just lack of wiki formatting:-) (you can set `\leftmarginiii` and friends to 0 if you must)